# How do I insert updated stackflair image in the Outlook 2010 signature?

Tags: images, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

I'm looking to setup my SU email within outlook.  I want to be able to have my signature display my updated version of stackflair.  However I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.  I tried using html, but it didn't seem to work:

[image]

However it only send the text within the email and not the actual picture:

[image]

Any ideas of how to make this happen?

[image]

## Update

I've been able to attach the image using the 'insert image' and copying the url to the image, however it doesn't update with current scores:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a space in `<imgsrc=` to make it `<img src=`?

Alternatively, what happens when you click on that little image icon (the one to the right of `Business Card`?

Comment: by placing a space in "imgsrc" I get the same thing.  the image icon is for locally saved files only, and doesn't allow for hyperlink images.

Comment: I've updated my question as well.

Comment: What happens when you look at the HTML after having inserted the attached image? Can you then modify it from there to work?

Comment: I'm unable to view any html.  I think what happens is Outlook downloads the image and saves on the PC and then pulls the image from there.